# Skip reading strings in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv

Is there is easy command in MATLAB which prevents program from crashing when it reads characters?

I use `xlsread` to read a (20 400) matrix data , the first row and column get disregarded
as they have  headers, so that:

```
data = xlsread ('C:\file.xls')
```

results in `data` with a size of (19 399).

I have a problem, some cells have missing data and it's written 'missing' and on some data sets i have headers reappear in middle.

Is there a way to skip these characters  without the program crashing and me having to open the file in excel and deleting those fields?

Thanks

---

sorry for the late update. Here is the code i am using:

```
[a,patha]=uigetfile({'*.csv'},'Select the file' ,'c:\Data\2010'); 
file1=[patha a]; 

%# get a file ID 
fid = fopen(file1,'rt'); 
newf= textscan(fid, ['%s' repmat('%f',1,27)], 'HeaderLines', 1, 'Delimiter', ','); 
fclose(fid) ;

%//Make time a datenum of the first column
time = datenum(newf{1} );

%//Find the difference in minutes from each row
timeDiff = round(diff(datenum(time)*(24*60)));

%//the rest of the data
newf = cell2mat(newf(2:28));
```

the error i get is:

```
??? Error using ==> cat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in ==> cell2mat at 81
            m{n} = cat(2,c{n,:});

Error in ==> testprogram at 31
pwr = cell2mat(newf(2:28));
```

it is due to the  characters in my file i selected. it disappears when i manually delete them

Comment: `xlsread` is all that's available to read `.XLS` files.  Maybe you can use Excel to export the data to CSV, and then use `dlmread` or `textscan`?  Alternatively, you could put `xlsread` in a `try-catch` block to avoid the crash.  You could even call `xlsread` on one line at a time, using the `range` parameter, and let the `try-catch` logic skip lines with bad data.

Comment: Ok even for the .txt and .csv i have the same question, how do i read them when there are characters  in middle of file on some rows

Comment: @Paul: What MATLAB version are you using?

Comment: I have R2009b, so its version specific?

Comment: @Paul: It would help if you told us *how* the program is crashing.

Comment: @Paul: I agree with gnovice. Xlsread should not crash on finding non-numerical values. It's much more likely that your program crashes, so if you can at least put up the error message you get, we be of more use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Textscan fails if the string doesn't match the expectation. The empty entries lead to problems when catenating - your array would have an uneven number of columns.

```
textscan('bla,5.4,missing,3,3,3.4','%s%f%f%f%f%f','Delimiter',',')

ans = 

    {1x1 cell}    [5.4000]    [0x1 double]    [0x1 double]    [0x1 double]    [0x1 double]
```

However, you can use'TreatAsEmpty', to treat 'missing' as empty (i.e. they're replaced by NaNs)

```
textscan('bla,5.4,missing,3,3,3.4','%s%f%f%f%f%f','Delimiter',',','TreatAsEmpty','missing')

ans = 

    {1x1 cell}    [5.4000]    [NaN]    [3]    [3]    [3.4000]
```

This allows you to run cell2mat without problems.

Comment: Anyway to use the smimilar code when we do not know what the string is? for example if the header reappears in middle of file

Comment: Textscan is excellent if you know what the string is. If you don't, I'd go with xlsread (or with textread followed by tests for what the input is like).

Comment: here is the code for the dlmread on the file [c,pathc]=uigetfile({'*.txt'},'Select the data','V:\data); file=[pathc c]; data= dlmread(file, ',', 1,4);  How do i incorporate the txtread here?

Comment: Hm, this is a bit complicated. I guess you better ask a new question - wait you already did, right? Never mind then.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know specifically what problem you are having that is causing your program to crash, because you haven't told us how you are trying to process the data you get from [XLSREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html). However, maybe this will help...

You can have [XLSREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html) return numeric, text, and raw data from the file in the following way:

```
[numData,txtData,rawData] = xlsread('C:\file.xls');
```

For this calling syntax:

- The variable `numData` will contain only numeric values from the spreadsheet. Any cells containing non-numeric data are set to [NaN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html).
- The variable `txtData` will contain only text data from the spreadsheet. Any cells containing numeric data are set to an empty string (`''`).
- The variable `rawData` will contain all the raw unprocessed cell content from the spreadsheet, both numeric and text.

Perhaps you can use these different forms for the data to help you deal with your additional character fields. I'm guessing that part of your problem may result from the fact that the numeric data you are processing may have [NaN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html) values in it (in places where there was text in the file) and your processing steps aren't taking this into account.

Comment: [c,pathc]=uigetfile({'*.txt'},'Select the data','V:\data); file=[pathc c]; data= dlmread(file, ',', 1,4); Above is my code . anyway to use the code like you used above, so it does not stop if a row is written in strings in middle of the file.