# matlab's xlsread causes Excel to crash - how to stop this?

Tags: windows, excel, matlab

Using Matlab's xlsread function to read excel files (in the COM server mode) often causes windows to display the 'Excel stopped working' message.  The xlsread function returns the correct data from the spread sheet and matlab continues fine, but these crash messages are annoying and will eventually cause me to miss an actual problem as I now simply click them away.

Has anyone a good solution to this?

Comment: I use xlsread and have never had it crash.  Have you been able to recreate the problem on a different computer or different version of windows / excel / matlab?

Comment: Yes, this happens on both winXP and win7, with Office 2003 & 2007.  It only sometimes happens, mostly when reading more than a few spreadsheets one after another.

Comment: IF you are reading many worksheets from the same workbook, you can try: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22365-xlsread-m-for-faster-data-transfer.  Also, have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525903/skip-reading-strings-in-matlab.  My guess is something specific in your data or setup is causing the instability.

Comment: I think this is happening because the Excel files were from an earlier version of Excel, and Excel was trying its best to ask me if I wanted to recalculate the files before saving, but couldn't.  Opening each file manually then saving and closing, made these go away.

Comment: I recommend you to post the answer, otherwise the question will remain open.

Answer (score 1):

The asker posted the answer he found himself as a comment:

> I think this is happening because the Excel files were from an earlier
>   version of Excel, and Excel was trying its best to ask me if I wanted
>   to recalculate the files before saving, but couldn't. Opening each
>   file manually then saving and closing, made these go away.